# Google Cloud Storage Force Download

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am storing my files in Google Cloud Storage. I would like to provide downloadable links. For example https://yeketakclub.storage.googleapis.com/audios/yeketak.club-dm7aEYv7R53JRlti3HHn.mp3 one of audio files stored in google cloud storage. But when it is clicked browser tries to open it. Is it possible to force download?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is necessarily a Google Cloud Storage issue (I might be wrong). The link provided there is downloadable. It just happens to be that your browser "prefers" to play it most probably because it recognises the MIME Type as one that can be handled.

In Chrome for instance, you can force download of the file by using <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>.

Or you can right click and save link as...

[image: right click to save file]

Comment: Yes in that case it is possible. But I need to force download when it is clicked.

Comment: I haven't tried, but you can force a content type of say `application/octet-stream`? That way the browser won't have any opinions. You can use the gsutil tool https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WorkingWithObjectMetadata

Comment: I will try it now.

Answer (score 15):

The correct answer is neither of these! (if you don't want to edit a file's metadata) Add this on the end of any signed url:

```
&response-content-disposition=attachment;
```

This will make all storage links force a download instead of opening.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I get an xml error that says the object does not exist.

Comment: Works perfectly for Google Storage SignedURLs.

Comment: For anyone finding this now - doesn't seem to work anymore (appending to the generated signed url). Now you can add response-content-disposition as an option when generating the signed url, e.g. for the PHP SDK add the following to the options array passed to the signedUrl method: 'responseDisposition' => 'attachment'

Comment: i cannot tell you how many hours i lost fussing around w/ my IAM service policies and a bunch of wacky stuff. My signed urls for images were loading fine on my website, but when i tried to download them, i would get Access-Control-Allow-Origin when using the url w/ the fetch() JS function. Attaching this to the end of my signed url, i was able to get download to work w/ a simple <a href=url download>Press Me</a> element! Than you a thousand!

Comment: @klopez glad it still helps someone!! I remember long time ago having the same issue

Answer (score 9):

You can signal browsers to download the object while still retaining an accurate content type by setting the content disposition to attachment. For, example using gsutil you can do this like so:

`gsutil setmeta -h 'Content-Disposition:attachment' gs://yeketakclub/audios/yeketak.club-dm7aEYv7R53JRlti3HHn.mp3`

Now your object can still have the correct content type of "audio/mpeg3" (or whatever happens to match the object's content).

Comment: This is exactly what I did.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Console bucket area you can click the menu and edit metadata on the object and set the **Content-Disposition** to **attachment**

[image]
[image]