# Google Cloud Storage and React - How to get a downloadable URL for an object

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-storage

I've tried generating a signed URL to access my object, but it's not a downloadable link.
Downloadable, as in, not being directed to a new page where I have to right click, save as in order to download an image, for example.

As for this code

```
/**
 * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following lines before running the sample.
 */
// The ID of your GCS bucket
// const bucketName = 'your-unique-bucket-name';

// The ID of your GCS file
// const fileName = 'your-file-name';

// The path to which the file should be downloaded
// const destFileName = '/local/path/to/file.txt';

// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

async function downloadFile() {
  const options = {
    destination: destFileName,
  };

  // Downloads the file
  await storage.bucket(bucketName).file(fileName).download(options);

  console.log(
    `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName} downloaded to ${destFileName}.`
  );
}

downloadFile().catch(console.error);
```

I have no idea how to integrate this into my backend using React as a frontend.  All it does is it saves a file into a local directory.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That code isn't using the signed URL that you said you were able to generate.  Also I don't see how this code could actually runs in a React frontend. The GCP SDKs are for backend code only.  It requires nodejs.  If you want to deal with a storage bucket from your frontend, you should be using a Firebase SDK for that.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893153/google-cloud-storage-force-download).

All I had to do was attach

```
&response-content-disposition=attachment;
```

to the end of my signed URLs.

Comment: Provide a link to the answer you used.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36893153/google-cloud-storage-force-download